# c# Webspider dictionary

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I try to create a spider web in C # .
I want to use a dictionary that reads each line (ie a URL) and get the same info.
I can not get out of the loop when there are more links to this url

> Console.WriteLine (" no link ");

In debug mode I get the following information:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for the line "}
>   while (link.Length> 0);

Here is my code, if you can help me get started with my first program I would be very happy :)

Comment: when link is null and you try to check length it will give you error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." you need to fix your loop condition.

Comment: thanks of your answer, but I don't see where to fix my problem ..

Comment: i didn't give you answer.. i gave you suggestion.. which would have fixed your problem.. Look @fcuesta's answer that's what i was talking about..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
} while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(link));
```

instead of:

```
} while (link.Length > 0);
```

It seems that your link variable is null, you will get a NullReferenceException if you try to access a property of a variable that is null.